# Resizing behavior with listbox with content

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, resize

I have a usercontrol containing a heading, a listbox and a button in the bottom.

When the listbox is filled with elements, I want the listbox to stretch to a maximium height, showing vertical scrollbars and the botton elements should be right below the listbox.

If someone resizes the window, the listbox should resize (respecting maxheight property) and show scrollbars when it needs to. I also want the save button to be right beneath the listbox and not in the bottom part of the usercontrol

I have found this to be really hard, once the listbox is filled with elements, it stretches out, no matter what.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Height="300" Width="525">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView Grid.Row="0" MaxHeight="100">
                <ListView.Items>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                    <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
        <Separator Grid.Row="2" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Width="75" Content="Save"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original XAML seemed to be quite strange... I'm not surprised it wasn't working. For example, you set the `ListView.MaxHeight` property to `100`, but also set the relevant `RowDefinition.MaxHeight` property to `150`. Perhaps you meant to do that, I don't know... either way, you just needed to use the `*` setting for the `Height` property on the `ListView`s `RowDefinition`, set some `VerticalAlignment` properties and remove the inner `Grid` that did nothing useful. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.Items>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
    <Separator Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Width="75" Height="25" Content="Save"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

When working with `Grid`s, just experiment with the `"*"` setting, which will take up all of the remaining space in the `Grid`. It's really not that difficult. Try this instead:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading"/>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" MaxHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.Items>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
    <Separator Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Width="75" Height="25" Content="Save"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

Ok, so this should now be what you're after:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.Items>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
    <Separator Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Width="75" Height="25" Content="Save"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for looking into this! More clarifications: If we stretch the usercontrol vertically, I want a max-height to limit the listbox and I also want the save-button to be just beneath the listbox. (In your example, the save-button floats down if you set the height to say 400 using you example above)

Comment: Well, the problem is that the listbox doesn't resize if it's filled with elements. If you take your last example, set the height to 100 the separator element and the button disappear. We want the listbox to change it's height (respecting some MinHeight).

Comment: I'll see if I can take another look later, but I'm out of time for now. A note for future use of this website... this is what happens when you don't put all of your requirements into your question in the first place... you waste peoples' time, each time you add another requirement. Please clearly edit your question to include *all* of your requirements and I'll see if I can return later.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being unclear. This will do for now. I can tidy it up with a little code-behind. Thanks!